# Передача даты и времени между формами

Tags: php, html, дата, время

Человек вводит "имя" и "сообщение", к сообщению прикрепляется дата+время.
Потом данные попадают в блокнот и в index.html считываются из него. Но время и дата "undefined"

Function.php

```
<?php date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Moscow");
$date = date("m.d.y");
$time = date("H:i:s");
file_put_contents("messages.txt",file_get_contents("messages.txt")."\n$name;$message;$date;$time");
<...>
    $result[$i]["name"] = $temp[0];
    $result[$i]["message"+ $date + $time] = $temp[1];
}
echo json_encode($result);}?>
```

Index.html

```
<...>
var start = array.length;
            array = response;
            var messages = document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML;
            for (i = start; i < array.length; i++) {                    
            messages = "<p><b>" + array[i].name + ":</b> " + array[i].message+array[i].$date+array[i].$time+"</p>";
```

Comment: *в index.html считываются из него* - как ?

Comment: Обратите внимание, что у `file_put_contents` есть третий аргумент, вы можете указать `FILE_APPEND` и дописывать файл.

Comment: @Alex вот весь код который выше var start = ...

 var xmlhttp = getXmlHttp();
 xmlhttp.open("POST", "functions.php", true);
 xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 xmlhttp.send("update=1");
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
   if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    var response = xmlhttp.responseText;
    response = JSON.parse(response);
    if (array.length == response.length) return;